# Stag party vs. Bachelor party

Tags: meaning, differences

Do they mean the same *"a men-only party"* or are there differences in their specific usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the entry for *stag party* in Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang*, first edition (1960):

> **stag party 1** A party attended by men only, often for the purpose of viewing obscene performances or movies, telling obscene jokes, and the like. **2** Specif., such a party given in honor of a prospective bridegroom by his friends.

Robert Chapman, *New Dictionary of American Slang* (1986) doesn't give *stag party* a separate entry, but mentions it in the entry for *stag*:

> **stag 1 *n*** fr early 1900s A man who goes to a party alone, without a woman partner **2 *adj*** For men only; without women: *a stag function* **3 *adv:*** *Several of the brothers were [going to the dance] 'stag'*—P Marks [*Plastic Age* (1924)] **4 *n*** (also **stag party**) A party for men only: *His shoulders were as broad as broad as the jokes at a Legion stag*—J Evans [*Halo in the Blood* (1946)]

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) alters the wording of definition 4 in Chapman from "A party for men only" to

> A party for men only, as a bachelor party

As for the term *bachelor party*, in the United States it almost always refers to a "farewell to bachelorhood" party thrown for a soon-to-be-married man by his male friends. An example of this usage is evident in the subtitle to James Oliver Cury, [*The Playboy Guide to Bachelor Parties*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HB9XE7QlsawC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22bachelor+party%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAg4DN3JTPAhVP02MKHdzfAAsQ6AEIQDAC#v=onepage&q=%22bachelor%20party%22&f=false) (2003):

> Everything You Need to Know About Planning the Groom's Rite of Passage—from Simple to Sinful

A Google Books search for "a bachelor party" turns up a match from not later than 1826 in which the term seems to refer simply and generally to a gathering of single men, without any hint of wild behavior, sexual hanky-panky, or imminent matrimony. From William Beattie, [*Journal of a Residence in Germany*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kknVBkCUhAYC&pg=PA263&dq=%22a+bachelor+party%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih9-2XjZXPAhVS1mMKHewhBvE4RhDoAQhKMAc#v=onepage&q=%22a%20bachelor%20party%22&f=false), volume 2 (1831):

> [Meiningen] 28th — I dropped in at a small **bachelor's party** this evening, and just in time to hear the conclusion of a warm debate on the respective merits of black and blue eyes. Both, it appears, are doing mischief,—but perhaps unconsciously.

Likewise Dickens's *The Posthumous Papers of the Pickwick Club* (1838) devotes a chapter to "[A Bachelor's Party, Given by Mr. Bob Sawyer at His Lodgings in the Borough](https://books.google.com/books?id=4xkGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22a+bachelor+party%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH9ePikJXPAhUXzGMKHfraCWI4WhDoAQg2MAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20bachelor%20party%22&f=false)." This party involves a large supper, copious drinking, some choruses of "A Frog He Would a-Courting Go," and multiple intrusions by an irate landlady, who eventually sends all of the guests home.

It's not unthinkable that *bachelor party* may still occasionally be used to refer to any party to which only unwedded men are invited—in which case it would have approximately as general a meaning as *stag party*—but I haven't found an instance of such use in recent Google Books search results.

The emphasis on obscene activity in the 1960 Wentworth & Flexner entry for *stag party*, by the way, explains the emergence of the slang term *stag film*, which (in the *Mad Men* era and afterward) referred to pornographic movies often shown at all-male get-togethers.

Answer (score 6):

While they do have the same meaning, it is not simply a men-only party.

It is a party before the stag (groom) gets married.  Traditionally the evening before the wedding but more often nowadays a few days before.

Answer (score 3):

According to wikipedia: Yes they are the same.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_party

> "A bachelor party (in the United States), also known as a stag party,
>   stag night, stag do (in Great Britain, Ireland, and Canada), a "buck's
>   party" (in Australia)[1] or a maanhaar partytjie (in South Africa),[…]"

Comment: I don't know where the Wikipedia article obtained its information: in Canada,  *bachelor party* is by far the commonest form that I have heard, with *stag party* used rarely (likely only by ex-pat Brits), and I have never heard *stag night* or *stag do*.